# button trigger doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, button, triggers

When the user tries to delete a customer, a pop up appears giving a list of reasons. Under this is a delete button which calls the delete function in the code behind. 
But the button isn't getting triggered, and I'm not getting any errors so I don't know why it isn't working

The first button just displays the pop up dialog and the second button calls the btnDelete_Click function.

Buttons:

```
 <a runat="server" id="btnDelete" style="float:right;"  class="btnDeleteLarge" href="#" onclick="OpenDeleteDialog()">Delete</a>  
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDeleteReason" CssClass="btnDeleteLarge"  ToolTip="Delete customer" style="float:right;display:none" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" Text="Delete"  />
```

Javascript:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args)
    {
        $("#dvAddReason").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            appendTo: "form",
            buttons: {
                'Delete': function () {
                    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete customer?')){
                        $('#<%=btnDeleteReason.ClientID %>').trigger('click');
                        }
                    },                
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
        });
    }

    function OpenDeleteDialog(){
        $("#dvAddReason").dialog("open");
    }
```

so the problem is with the line `$('#<%=btnDeleteReason.ClientID %>').trigger('click');`. The trigger isn't working and the `btnDelete_Click` never gets called.

I also tried changing the button to a link button:

```
<asp:LinkButton Visible="true" runat="server" ID="btnDeleteReason" OnClick="btnDelete_Click">LinkDelete</asp:LinkButton>
```

Then call `__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnDeleteReason', '');` in the javascript. But this didn't work either.

Comment: Do you need open and closed parentheses after btnDelete_Click? `btnDelete_Click()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd say your selector is very weird. `#<%=btnDeleteReason.ClientID %>` i see what you're trying to do but i dont think it'd work that way. You gotta resolve what `<%=btnDeleteReason.ClientID %>` means first ( i guess it'll give you smth like `btnDeleteReason.23` ) and then use it as a selector ( `$('#btnDeleteReason.23').trigger('click')` )

PS : Perhaps this could work : `$('#<%=btnDeleteReason.ClientID %>').click();`

PPS : try to console.log('<%=btnDeleteReason.ClientID %>') to see what it gives you.